# Install mingw and msys to run c programs on windows

Tags: windows-7, mingw, msys

I installed MinGW by using **mingw-get-inst-20111118.exe** and it works but it is very slow!

I don't want to install it online, I remember that I have previously installed MinGW and msys by using two files **mingw.exe** and **msys.exe** without using the internet and it was great, but now I cant repeat what I have done and I cant find a link to **mingw.exe**!

Please, I want a simple steps for better offline installation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wrote myself a small aide-memoire the other day on how to update (or set up) my MinGW and MSYS installation for building 32 and 64 programs on Windows. I doesn't involve mingw-get so you may have to go fetch any additional stuff manually but I think it includes pretty much all you might need.

It goes like this:

### MinGW Environment

- Download the latest 32 and 64 bit MinGW builds from [MinGW builds on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/)

eg:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.7.2/64-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/x64-4.7.2-release-posix-sjlj-rev2.7z/download

and

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.7.2/32-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/x32-4.7.2-release-posix-sjlj-rev2.7z/download

Use the Posix threads sjlj version

- Unzip the 32 bit version to eg c:\mingw
- Unzip the 64 bit version over the top

### MSYS

- Copy MSys directory from previous installation into c:\mingw\msys\1.0 or get an updated version from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/) and unzip it.

eg: [MSYS-20111123](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/MSYS-20111123.zip/download)

Add c:\mingw\bin and c:\mingw\msys\1.0\bin to path

Answer (score 0):

What I did was get mingw-get-setup from the website and installed everything (w/ g++/g) and ran g++/g commands. Don't forget to change the PATH environment to MinGW